# Microsoft teams: filesFolder is returning 404 for a newly created team/channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-files

We are using the below graph endpoint to get the metadata for the location where the files of a channel are stored.

```
GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/filesFolder
```

Sometimes for a newly created MS team/channel it is returning 404 not found.

```
GET
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
client-request-id: c5346ac2-b438-4852-84da-d8f9d257ed66
request-id: 299100d3-fb5e-41e2-a3a4-f04ec11d21b4
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 26 Jun 2020 07:54:13 GMT
request-id: 299100d3-fb5e-41e2-a3a4-f04ec11d21b4

{
  "error": {
    "code": "NotFound",
    "message": "SharePoint folder not found for this channel.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-26T07:54:13",
      "request-id": "299100d3-fb5e-41e2-a3a4-f04ec11d21b4"
    }
  }
}
```

It looks like Ms teams is not creating a folder for a new channel. Previously this used to work.

Do we have any alternative API to create a folder for a MS team channel?

Comment: This is bug. As of now there is no workaround for this. SP site/FilesFolders will be created when you visit "Files" for newly created Teams/Channels.

Answer (score 0):

This applies not only to files. For example let say you create a group and immediately try to add owner/member to the newly created group id, most probably you'll get 404 error. But if you wait like 10-15 seconds and try again, you succeed. This applies to files and many other and some may take several minutes or hours to be created.

For example i created several classrooms on teams using api and it took more than an hour for Files/Assignments/Class Notebook/Grades tabs to be fully functional.

I believe this is because Microsoft has many datacenters and it takes some time to propagate changes to all datacenter or at least the ones closer to you.